# Can Sendmail rewrite a specific To: address, so that a different email shows up in the To line?

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendmail

I have requirement to rewrite a single recipient address.   Not just aliasing, because the email To: lines has to be changed.   I.e.,.

I tried adding this to `sendmail.mc`:

```
FEATURE(`genericstable')dnl
GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/genericsdomain')
```

Then I add the following to `/etc/mail/genericstable`, in order that foobar@bongo.com gets changed to foo@gmail.com:

```
foobar@bongo.com        foo@gmail.com
```

Then I add both domains to `/etc/mail/genericsdomain` (both are on separate lines:

```
bongo.com
gmail.com
```

Should that now rewrite `foobar@bongo.com` to `foo@gmail.com`?

It's not working, it's still trying to send to `foobar@bongo.com`   I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sendmail: Rewriting selected header recipient addresses

See [`FEATURE(genericstable)`](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/features.html#genericstable) - Remark about `FEATURE(allmasquerade)` is crucial in your case.

Comment: I edited my original question, as I couldn't get this feature to work.

Comment: By default genericstable rewrites only header sender addresses .  FEATURE(allmasquerade) changes default behavior.